# Is Matrix $A^2$ invertible if $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to say that squaring is a form of scaling so that it should be true; however I can't make sense out of it and clearly see why.

The problem is that while it's a form of scaling, if we think about a matrix as a list of coefficients of variables of a system of equations, then the coefficients are being multiplied among all the variables.

For example, with the simple scaling by a single value of a matrix, a system of equations would retain the same exact solutions it had before scaling.
However, when squaring the matrix (I tried with a specific example), the solutions differ in the squared version of the system.

Comment: try to calculate $A^2 * A^{-1} * A^{-1}$

Comment: Follow Thomas' advice. And what do you know about the inverse of a product of invertible matrices?

Comment: The *proof* is extremely short, so I imagine you are looking for intuition.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes exactly thank you. I can see the Algebra justifying it, but I'm not getting an intuition for it.

Comment: It gets more complicated this way, but multiplying by a matrix transforms the unit hypercube into a "hyperparallelogram." The (absolute value of) the determinant gives us the "volume" scaling factor. If the matrix is not invertible, there is a lowering of dimension, the volume becomes $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks, this makes sense. So basically the product, regardless of order, of two invertible matrices is always invertible?

Comment: Yes, and the volume scaling factor given by the product is the product of the individual scaling factors. In the case of invertible $A$, the volume scaling factor of $A^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of the volume scaling factor of $A$.

Comment: Intuition: Think of the matrix $A$ as a linear transformation. Then $A^2$ represents applying that linear transformation twice. Suppose you start with a vector $x$, apply $A$ once to get $y=Ax$, then apply it again to get $z=Ay=A^2x$. The inverse is a way to get from $z$ back to $x$, which you can do by undoing $A$ twice: from $z$ you get $y=A^{-1}z$ and then $x=A^{-1}y=A^{-2}z$. In short: $x\xrightarrow{A}y\xrightarrow{A}z$ so $x\xleftarrow{A^{-1}}y\xleftarrow{A^{-1}}z$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, ahh…this explains a lot of things, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Even though Linear Algebra is "algebra," geometric intuition can be useful, particularly when you come to eigenvalues, eigenvectors.

Comment: @Rahul, thank you, that's a great intuitive explanation, very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, the product of two invertible $n\times n$ matrices is invertible:

> if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ invertible matrices, then $AB$ is invertible and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

The proof is just by checking that $(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})=I_n$ (the $n\times n$ identity matrix):
$$
(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})=A(B(B^{-1}A^{-1}))=
A((BB^{-1})A^{-1}))=A(I_nA^{-1})=AA^{-1}=I_n
$$
Similarly (although not really needed) you can prove that
$(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)=I_n$.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Moreover $(A^2)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^2.$ Note that

$$(A^{-1})^2A^2=A^{-1}A^{-1}AA=A^{-1}IA=A^{-1}A=I.$$

Answer (score 8):

Yes. A square matrix $A$ is invertible iff $\det A \neq 0$. If $A$ is invertible, then $\det A^2 = \det A \cdot \det A \neq 0$, so $A^2$ is invertible.